# Python: How to split string but preserve the non-alphanumeric characters

Tags: python, split

I face problem when I am dealing with this:

```
Sample string - \"H\00E6tta\"
```

*\00E6 is an unicode and my script able to understood it despite of not in usual form \u00e6. So please do not worry over that part.

I would expect after split something like:

```
['', '"H', "00E6tta", '"'] - first white column is normal as nothing before the '\' when I split
```

I did this:

```
sub_glyph = glyph.split("\\")
```

However this is the result I got:

```
['', 'H', '00E6tta', '']
```

Any clue? I would need the " to convert into unicode. But it just gone missing now. I am confused thought I split accordingly to '\' and why the " will be gone. Can't find any resourceful guide online, need help.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a raw string (prepending string with `r` makes it a raw string) and `split` it:

```
s = r'\"H\00E6tta\"'

print(s.split('\\'))
# ['', '"H', '00E6tta', '"']
```

*Note*: When we make `s` a raw string, the "literal" string (here) actually changes to `\\"H\\00E6tta\\"` (use `repr(s)` to view the change). This makes our `split` possible.

Comment: Thanks for you comment. Never aware the difference of string and raw string thingy before hand. Learnt something here, again thanks.